Android App Unable to resolve host when connecting custom DNS via wifi
I am working on a task to update app ssl cert pinning. Server is currently using Cloudflare CDN to proxy old cert and installed new cert on AWS api gateway.
Now, I have to verify if the new ssl cert pinning is valid. I setup the custom DNS Server with dnsmasq on macOS and route the domain to AWS api gateway directly. Then connect all testing devices to the DNS Server.
What I am facing is iOS test succeed but Android seems not able to execute test correctly. On macOS , config wifi DNS and open iOS Simulator, old cert will cause SSL handshake error, new cert handshake successfully. On Android emulator or even physical device, I have configured the wifi with static ip + custom dns server ip. I did some test on routing some website to google.com and tested with Chrome is working(Chrome will warn user and block the traffic). As for the App with OkHttp client, it keep throw java.net.UnknownHostException for that domain.
I was expecting App connection will works with wifi config, resolve domain from custom DNS server, so that I can verify the new cert pinning works.
Does anyone have experience on this kind of test and know why App seems not respect the DNS server configured on wifi connection?
